# Point image request to a higher folder thru htaccess

Tags: html, .htaccess

Is there any rule I can write to make all requests to my image folder point up one folder. I'm dealing with a lot of links so I don't want to put ../

Eg: http://hostingxtreme.com/ajax/images/logo.png.

**Should become** http://hostingxtreme.com/images/logo.png

Thanks

Here the code I'm using
Dosent seem to be working!
    `php_value register_long_arrays On

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^/?ajax/images/logo.png$ /images/logo.png [L,R=301]

    </IfModule>`

Answer (score 1):

In the htaccess file in your document root, add either:

```
Redirect 301 /ajax/images/logo.png /images/logo.png
```

Or if you need to use mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?ajax/images/logo.png$ /images/logo.png [L,R=301]
```

Comment: @RohanJM The rule needs to go *before* your routing rules. The routing rules catch everything and point them to `/index.php` so the redirect will never happen. You need to add it right under the `RewriteBase /` line.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible for it to work without putting logo.png? So basically map ajax/images to /images

Comment: @RohanJM You mean like: `RewriteRule ^/?ajax/images/(.*)$ /images/$1 [L,R=301]`?

Answer (score 0):

I got it!

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (ajax/|ajax/.*/)images/(.*)  
RewriteRule (ajax/|ajax/.*/)images/(.*) images/$2  

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (ajax/|ajax/.*/)stylesheets/(.*)  
RewriteRule (ajax/|ajax/.*/)stylesheets/(.*) stylesheets/$2
```